# can you sqoop from hive db to another hive db?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

we have 2 different Hadoop clusters, and I was wondering if you can sqoop data between hive dbs/tables.
I've been looking for this for a while but i can't find it.

```
Cluster1:                    Cluster2
db: metrics                  db:metrics
table: disk                  table: disk
```

output on Cluster2:

```
db: metrics
table:disk
where disk= Cluster1.disk Union Cluster2.disk
```

really, I can add the logic easy, I just wanted to know if you can use sqoop to import data from hive to hive.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop doesn't do that. Try using Apache Falcon version 0.4 which adds support for Hive replication.